# How do you alter a variable's value from within a for loop?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm learning Rust and I wrote a little program that's supposed to return the nth word in a sentence.

My issue is that the counter I have to keep track of whether I've reached the specified n, as I increment it, does not remain incremented for the next iteration, but starts over at 1. This would appear to be an issue with how lifetimes work in Rust that I don't yet understand. If someone could let me know if I am missing something here, that would be helpful.

Here is my main.rs file:

```
fn main() {
    let first_string = String::from("There is a sentence here.");

    let answer_01 = return_nth_word(&first_string, 3);
    println!("Word 3 in {}: {}", first_string, answer_01);

}

fn return_nth_word(s: &str, idx: usize) -> &str {
    let bytes = s.trim().as_bytes();

    let mut count: usize = 1;
    let mut begin: usize = 0;

    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if count <= idx {
            if item == b' ' {
                println!{"Index at space: {}", i};
                if count == idx {
                    let mut end = i + 1;
                    return &s[begin..end];
                }
                let mut begin = idx + 1;
                println!("COUNT BEFORE: {}", count);  //printing here to demonstrate failed iteration
                let mut count = count + 1;
                println!("COUNT AFTER: {}", count);   //printing here to demonstrate failed iteration

                // The problem is the variable in the for
                // loop does not change the variable
                // outside of it. So I need to find another
                // way of iterating over that.

            }
        }
    }
    s
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Index at space: 5
COUNT BEFORE: 1
COUNT AFTER: 2         
Index at space: 8
COUNT BEFORE: 1
COUNT AFTER: 2 <---- count continually increments from 1 to 2 on each iteration instead of counting up
Index at space: 10
COUNT BEFORE: 1
COUNT AFTER: 2
Index at space: 19
COUNT BEFORE: 1
COUNT AFTER: 2
Word 3 in There is a sentence here.: There is a sentence here.
```

Comment: You should also have seen a `warning: unused variable` and several `warning: variable does not need to be mutable`s when you compiled this code. Those warnings exist to point you in the right direction so it's hard to overlook a mistake like using `let` unnecessarily. Pay attention to what the compiler tries to warn you about!

Comment: For what it's worth, you can replace the entire body of `return_nth_word` with `s.split(' ').nth(idx - 1).unwrap()` instead. See [`str::split`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split), [`Iterator::nth`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth)

Comment: Nice! Thanks, guys. I had my function in with a bunch of others just adding them all to the same main.rs file, so I didn't notice those warnings. I didn't realize how shadowing would affect the value on iteration, but now it makes sense! And I appreciate you providing that standard function for the sake of having it, @trentcl. :)